# In Haskell, how to putStrLn works in foldLeft

Tags: haskell

#### TL;DR.

```
foldLeft (\_ x -> putStrLn x) (pure ()) ("2":."1":.Nil)
```

Why the above code outputs

```
1
```

rather than

```
2
1
```

#### Full question

I am doing exercise of fp-course
https://github.com/system-f/fp-course/blob/5e0848b4eacb3ddff65553ab5beb6447b73f61b3/src/Course/FileIO.hs#L97

I have figured 2 solutions for this.

```
printFiles ps = void . sequence $ (uncurry printFile) <$> ps
```

```
printFiles = foldLeft (\_ (fp, content) -> printFile fp content) (pure ())
```

The first is right and can print as question's ask.

```
>> :main "share/files.txt"
============ share/a.txt
the contents of a

============ share/b.txt
the contents of b

============ share/c.txt
the contents of c
```

The second print as follow.

```
>> :main "share/files.txt"
============ 
share/c.txt
the contents of c
```

It looks like `pure ()` only collect the last `printFile fp content` of `foldLeft`.
How to make `pure ()` aka `IO ()` collects all `putStrLn` in `foldLeft`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Haskell is referentially transparent, you can always answer such questions for yourself by evaluating the expression manually, i.e. inlining function calls and beta-reducing until it's obvious what's going on:

```
foldLeft (\_ x -> putStrLn x) (pure ()) ("2":."1":.Nil)
  = {- (recursive) definition of `foldLeft` for Cons case -}
    foldLeft (\_ x -> putStrLn x)
       ((\_ x -> putStrLn x) (pure ()) "2")
       ("1":.Nil)
  = {- beta reduction -}
    foldLeft (\_ x -> putStrLn x)
       (putStrLn "2")
       ("1":.Nil)
  = {- definition of `foldLeft` for Cons case -}
    foldLeft (\_ x -> putStrLn x)
       ((\_ x -> putStrLn x) (putStrLn "2") "1")
       Nil
  = {- beta reduction -}
    foldLeft (\_ x -> putStrLn x)
       (putStrLn "1")  -- woops, the "2" has vanished in the `_` argument
       Nil
  = {- definition of `foldLeft` for Nil case -}
    putStrLn "1"
```

So that's all you get: one print of `"1"`. OTOH, with Willem Van Onsem's suggestion it will be

```
foldLeft (\prev x -> prev >> putStrLn x) (pure ()) ("2":."1":.Nil)
  = {- definition of `foldLeft` for Cons case -}
    foldLeft (\prev x -> prev >> putStrLn x)
       ((\prev x -> prev >> putStrLn x) (pure ()) "2")
       ("1":.Nil)
  = {- beta reduction -}
    foldLeft (\prev x -> prev >> putStrLn x)
       (pure () >> putStrLn "2")
       ("1":.Nil)
  = {- definition of `foldLeft` for Cons case -}
    foldLeft (\prev x -> prev >> putStrLn x)
       ((\prev x -> prev >> putStrLn x) (pure () >> putStrLn "2") "1")
       Nil
  = {- beta reduction -}
    foldLeft (\prev x -> prev >> putStrLn x)
       ((pure () >> putStrLn "2") >> putStrLn "1")
       Nil
  = {- definition of `foldLeft` for Nil case -}
    pure () >> putStrLn "2" >> putStrLn "1"
```

Answer (score 5):

You construct a `putStrLn "1"` as end result, and that is thus produced. Beware that `IO a` is *not* an action that *took* place, or will always take place, you should see it as some sort of delegate to an action, so a recipe, and you can combine recipes with [**`(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-) which creates a *new* recipe that will first run the first operand, and then the right operand.

So in this case, we can fix it wiht:

```
foldLeft (\prev x -> prev >> putStrLn x) (pure ()) ("2":."1":.Nil)
```

so the end result will be a `putStrLn "2" >> putStrLn "1"` which is an `IO ()` and when invoked will first print `"2"` and then print `"1"`.